# compare the outcome of logistic regression (predictive probabilities) before and after an event

Tags: regression, probability, logistic, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models

To train a glm model, I'm using using clinical data (~10 features) of a large cohort of patients and healthy subjects. I'm using a smaller test group (around 20 people) and predict their outcome (healthy or patient) based on the training model.

Now, some of the patients in the test group underwent surgery and I want to compare the predictive probabilities before and after surgery using the initial training dataset. Looking at the probabilities, I would like to know whether those subjects are closer to the healthy group than they were before surgery.

Is there a quantitative way to compare the probability prediction before and after?

Comment: It sounds like you are interested in the causal effect of receiving surgery on whether a patient is healthy or not. Is that so?

Comment: The patients that have undergone surgery are only a few, so I built my model using the entire cohort (patients and healthy subjects) to determine whether the patients who underwent surgery (who were all categorized as patients before surgery in a predictive model) have a lesser "patient profile" afterward. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Again, it sounds like you are interested in the causal effect of surgery on a patient's "patient profile" (i.e., whether they are healthy or not). If so, use causal inference methods. The size of the sample has no bearing on the fundamental question you want to answer (which is what I am trying to get at), though it might effect specifically what method you use. Instead if thinking about "predicted probability", I want you to think about an ideal world where you don't need to predict but just have some variable measured exactly. What is that variable, and what would you do with it?

Comment: Thanks Noah. So Ideally, I would have something like a principal component analysis plot based on selected clinical data (ie. phenotype) that are able to separate 2 groups of samples significantly and that those 2 groups correspond to patients and healthy subjects. Then I would add the patients after surgery and see whether those subjects are closer to the patient group or the healthy group. Logistic regression can also represent an ideal scenario where the selected variables are able to differentiate the 2 group of subjects.